# re.findall() returning empty element on using \w*$ while it is expected to return only last word

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I was trying the python regular expression and was trying to get first and last word from the string using `^\w*` and `\w*$`. But I am getting the following results:

```
>>> re.findall(r'^\w*', 'This is a test string')
['This']

#to get the last word
>>> re.findall(r'\w*$', 'This is a test string')
['string', '']
```

can someone explain how this regexp works and why i am getting the empty element after string (`['string', '']`).
Note: It works with  `^\w+` and `\w+$`.

Comment: Try this it will give the first and last word `re.findall(r'^(\w+).*\b(\w+).*?$', 'This is a test string')`

Comment: A usual thing with regex: `.*` can match an empty string. `\w` only matches word chars, so `\w*` matches 0+ word chars, stops before the end of the string. That is the first match. Then, the second match comes as the regex also matches the empty string at the end.

Comment: Some may wonder why `$` does not "gobble" the end of string position: because it is a *zero-width assertion*, it does not consume the text (i.e. the regex index remains where it was before trying this pattern, it is a reason why `(?!^)` and `(?<!^)` (lookarounds are zero-width assertions, too) are equal).